# Why does RHEL7.2 can not find the file 'libgmp.so.3()(64bit)'

Tags: oracle, redhat

I am installing Oracle 11g on the my system RHEL7.2 64bit,But in this step,I can not continue to install it,Because I can not find a file on my system,It is 'libgmp.so.3'.

[image: Look about the picture]

So,like the picture,I can not install anything else.Because I had installed a higher level 'gmp' on my system.It is useless when I make a softlink to a higher level file.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
yum clean all
```

this is will clear the yum cache .

Comment: Please add some explanation to that call - why should one try that? Why do you think that it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try first install `mpfr-2.4.1-6.el6.x86_64.rpm`
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/ginnydbinstallonlinux-488779.html. (It is for Oracle Linux 6.0, but it describes your problem)

```
  # yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall
........
    ---> Package mpfr.x86_64 0:2.4.1-6.el6 will be installed

    --> Running transaction check

    ---> Package kernel-uek-headers.x86_64 0:2.6.32-300.32.1.el6uek will be installed

---> Package ppl.x86_64 0:0.10.2-11.el6 will be installed
```

Also see brief installation guide how to install libraries https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-db-11gr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-7

And of course big installation guide if nothing has helped https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#BHCFACHG